# ASP.net best way to run slow method

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, asynchronous

Given the method:

```
public static void SubmitNewTutorial()
{
    // Insert new tutorial method
    AddToDatabase();

    // Email notify anyone subscribed
    SendOutEmailNotifications();

    // Redirect to published tutorial page
    Redirect();
}
```

Where `SendOutEmailNotifications` can be slow (if there are tens of thousands of subscribers this can take over 30 seconds).

What is the best way to call `SendOutEmailNotifications` without having the author submitting the new tutorial having to wait 30 seconds before `Redirect()` is called?

Is attaching `SendOutEmailNotifications` to a new task the recommended way?

Comment: Try searching the web and this site for "asp.net background task". It's asked and answered daily, don't become a statistic.

Comment: `SendOutEmailNotifications` Should probably be queued in some external queue service that offloads mails once in a while, not inside the same ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)

Or try:

```
public static void SubmitNewTutorial()
  {
    // Insert new tutorial method
    AddToDatabase();

    // Email notify anyone subscribed
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => SendOutEmailNotifications());

    // Redirect to published tutorial page
    Redirect();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is slow but not too slow, I might run it on a separate thread as suggested above.  If it takes a long time, write the email details to the database and then have a totally different process get those details from the database and send the email.  I will often use a windows service for this.  In that way, it doesn't matter if it is 3 seconds behind or 3 minutes behind.